# Differential forms: algebraic curves vs Riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

I've tried to read about both Riemann surfaces and algebraic curves (over an algebraically closed field) and in both cases I found definitions of objects called differential forms (or 1-forms).

For instance, [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/246c-notes-1-meromorphic-functions-on-riemann-surfaces-and-the-riemann-roch-theorem/) meromorphic 1-forms on a Riemann surface are introduced as a set of expressions in the form $\omega dz$ that behave in a certain way with respect to chart changes. The same kind of definition is encountered in the book *Complex Algebraic Curves, F. Kirwan*.

On the other hand, books on algebraic curves such as *Algebraic curves, W. Fulton* introduce objects called differential 1-forms in an algebraic way (see also [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG14.pdf) for instance).

So I'm wondering:

- do both those concepts coincide or are related in the case of complex curves?
- if yes, how do we show this?
- also, which of those concepts emerged first chronologically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have any hope of this being true, we need to look at global differentials on projective curves (or compact riemann surfaces).

For example, take $C = \mathbb{C}$. Then, $\Omega^{alg}_{C}(C) = \mathbb{C}[z]dz \subsetneq \Omega^{an}_C(C)$, where the left and right hand sides denote global algebraic and analytic 1-forms respectively. The inclusion is strict since there are many entire functions which are not polynomials. (eg. $e^zdz \notin \Omega_{C}^{\text{alg}}(C)$).

If $C$ is a smooth projective curve, then this is true. In fact, we can show this holds for a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, using [GAGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry#:%7E:text=in%20chronological%20order.-,Riemann%27s%20existence%20theorem,making%20it%20an%20algebraic%20curve.). The content of the GAGA theorems is that if $X^{an}$  denotes the complex manifold over $\mathbb{C}$ obtained from $X$, then there is an operation $V \mapsto V^{an}$ which takes in an algebraic vector bundle of finite rank and outputs a complex analytic one of the same rank. Furthermore, there is a natural map $V \to V^{an}$ coming from the fact that algebraic forms are always analytic. This generalizes $\Omega_C^{alg} \subset  \Omega_{C}^{an}$.

The most relevant GAGA theorem to us is the following:

> The map $V \to V^{an}$ induces an isomorphism of sheaf cohomology $$H^i(X, V) \to H^i(X^{an}, V^{an})$$ for all $i \geq 0$.

Taking $i = 0$, $X = C$, and $V = \Omega^{alg}_C$ gives an affirmative answer to your first question when $C$ is compact. I won't say much about the proofs in GAGA; I just wanted to point out that for your second question, this is a special case of a very general phenomenon. (In fact, GAGA is usually stated in terms of coherent sheaves; a vast generalization of finite rank vector bundles.)

Lastly, I won't say a lot about the history since I don't know it well. The algebraic differentials here are also called [Kähler Differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential), which were introduced in the 1930s. On the other hand, differentials are a much older concept, and the credit for organizing (analytic) differential forms algebraically using exterior algebra is usually given to Élie Cartan and his 1899 paper.